# How can I use a roman font for capital letters in math mode when using plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, french

The French style (see the `frenchstyle` option of the LaTeX kpfonts package) is to typeset capital letters in math mode in [roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_type) rather than in italic.

How can I achieve that in plain TeX without having to manually input `\rm` everywhere? That is, I would the second one to look like the first in:

- `Let $\rm V$ be a vector space.`
- `Let $V$ be a vector space.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the mathcode of the capital letters. In `plain.tex` you find

```
% INITEX sets up \mathcode x=x, for x=0..255, except that
% \mathcode x=x+"7100, for x = `A to `Z and `a to `z;
% \mathcode x=x+"7000, for x = `0 to `9.
```

but you want `"7000`, the second digit denotes the default math family to take the character from, and `0` is for the upright text font.

How to do this with as less work as possible?

```
\count255=`A
\count8="7000
\advance\count255 by -1
\loop\ifnum\count255<`Z
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \advance\count8 by 1
  \mathcode\count255=\count8
\repeat
% cover your tracks
\count8=0

$A+B+\Gamma+Z+a+b+z$

${\mit A}+A$

\bye
```

[image]

If you use `pdftex`, this can be shortened to

```
\count255=`A
\advance\count255 by -1
\loop\ifnum\count255<`Z
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \mathcode\count255=\numexpr\count255+"7000\relax
\repeat
```

Even shorter with `expl3` (also requires `pdftex`):

```
\input expl3-generic
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnn { `A } { `Z }
  {
   \mathcode #1 = \int_eval:n { #1 + "7000 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I'd initialize `\count8` to `"7000` + `A` - 1 outside the loop then inside the loop just advance both `\count255` and `\count8` by 1. That'll save an extra assignment, although it doesn't especially matter in the big picture of things.

Comment: @DonHosek That's a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by changing the math code for the capital letters:¹

```
 \mathcode`\A="7041
 \mathcode`\B="7042
 ⋮
 \mathcode`\Z="705A
```

Each character has a four-nibble math associated with it. The last two nibbles give the character code, the first indicates the class, where `7` indicates a plain symbol which can change families and the second nibble gives the default family. The normal setting for Roman letters is to use the codes `"7141`…`"715A` which indicates that family 1 (math italic) should be used.

The `"` is essential, by the way and indicates that the number should be interpreted as hex. Otherwise, you'll get mysterious messages about family 11 not being defined (or, if it is, odd character results) since 7041 in hex is 1B81 which would be the (probably non-existant) character at code 129 from family 11 interpreted as a large operator.

---

1. This works in both plain TeX and LaTeX, by the way.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you